# Edit one .CSV using Information from Another

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two .csv files, one with a listing of employee ID's and a department identification number, and another with a listing of all equipment registered to them. The two files share the employee ID field, and I would like to take the department number from the first file and add it to each piece of the corresponding employee's equipment in the second file (or possibly output a third file with the joined information if that is the most expedient method). So far I have pulled the information I need from the first file and am storing it in a hash table, which I believe I should be able to use to compare to the other file, but I'm not sure exactly how to go about that. The other questions I have found on the site that may be related seem to be exclusively about checking for duplicates/changes between the two files. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code I have for creating the hashtable:

```
Import-Csv "filepath\filename.csv"|ForEach-Object -Begin{
    $ids = @{}
} -Process {
    $ids.Add($_.UserID,$_.'Cost Center')}
```

Edit:

Here is a sample of data:

First CSV:

```
UserID | Legal Name | Department
---------------------------------
XXX123| Namey Mcnamera | 1234

XXX321| Chet Manley | 4321

XXX000| Ron Burgundy | 9999
```

Second CSV:

```
Barcode | User ID | Department
--------------------------------

000000000000 | xxx123 | 0000
111111111111 | xxx123 | 0000
222222222222 | xxx123 | 0000
333333333333 | xxx321 | 0000
444444444444 | xxx321 | 0000
555555555555 | xxx000 | 0000
```

The second csv also has several more columns of data, but these three are the only ones I care about.

Edit 2:

Using this code from @wOxxOm (edited to add -force parameters as was receiving an error when attempting to write to department column due to an entry already existing):

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv "filename.csv"
$csv2 = Import-CSV "filename.csv"

$indexKey = 'UserID'
$index1 = @{}; foreach($row in $csv1){$index1[$row.$indexKey] = $row.'department'}

$copyfield = 'department'
foreach($row in $csv2){
    if ($matched = $index1[$row.'User ID']){
        Add-Member @{$copyField = $matched.$copyfield} -InputObject $row -Force
     }
}

export-csv 'filepath.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -InputObject $csv2 -Force
```

outputs the following information:

```
Count   Length  LongLength  Rank    SyncRoot    IsReadOnly  IsFixedSize IsSynchronized
48  48  48  1   System.Object[] FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

EDIT 3:

Got everything worked out with help from @Ross Lyons. Working code is as follows:

```
#First Spreadsheet
$users = Import-Csv "filepath.csv" 

#Asset Listing
$assets = Import-Csv "filepath.csv" 

[System.Array]$data = ""

#iterating through each row in first spreadsheet
foreach ($user in $users) {
      #iterating through each row in the second spreadsheet
      foreach ($asset in $assets) {
        #compare user ID's in each spreadsheet
        if ($user.UserID -eq $asset.'User ID'){
            #if it matches up, copy the department data, user ID and barcode from appropriate spreadsheets
            $data += $user.UserID + "," + $user."Department" + "," + $asset."Barcode" + ","
            }
        }

}
$data | Format-Table | Out-File "exportedData.csv" -encoding ascii -Force
```

Comment: Join-Object might make it easier http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/

Comment: Why don't you add a sample of the actual data in the question instead of that huge blob of text?

Comment: @wOxxOm, Because it is work-related information that is not available to the public.

Comment: @Ross Lyons, you can see the main changes I made to your code were removing the $export variable as it was an unnecessary intermediary and casting the $data variable as an array rather than setting up a string and splitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first, be gentle please, I'm still learning myself! Let me know if the following works or if anything is glaringly obviously wrong...

```
#this is your first spreadhseet with usernames & department numbers
$users = Import-Csv "spreadsheet1.csv"

#this is your second spreadsheet with equipment info & user ID's, but no department numbers
$assets = Import-Csv "spreadsheet2.csv"

#set a variable for your export data to null, so we can use it later
$export = ""

#iterating through each row in first spreadsheet
foreach ($user in $users) {
      #iterating through each row in the second spreadsheet
      foreach ($asset in $assets) {
        #compare user ID's in each spreadsheet
        if ($user.UserID -like $asset.'User ID')
            #if it matches up, copy the department data, user ID and barcode from appropriate spreadsheets
            $data = "$user.UserID" + "," + "$user.Department" + "," + "$asset.barcode" + "," + "~"

            #splits the data based on the "~" that we stuck in at the end of the string
            $export = $data -split "~" | Out-File "exportedData.csv" -Encoding ascii
            }

}
```

Let me know what you think. Yes, I know this is probably not the best or most efficient way of doing it, but I think it will get the job done.

If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll have another crack at it.

Comment: For some reason this is returning a spreadsheet with the length of each line as a string. I also notice the lengths are much longer than they should be. I'm not certain why this is, but one thing I noticed was you use $data = (rest of loop) in your foreach loop instead of $data += (rest of loop). After changing this line the problem persists, but without the change it only outputs one line, whereas with the change it at least outputs the correct number of lines.

Comment: Ahh! Change the `Export-Csv` to `out-file`. I think that should fix it. I'll amend the "answer" above

Comment: So, interesting results. This does output the information I need, but does so with several hundred rows of repeated arrays containing all the information in both spreadsheets repeated several times over. It still works much better than what I had previously, and I very much appreciate your courteous help. I would mention however that you are still using $data = instead of $data +=, which outputs only one line with each user id in a separate cell, whereas += results in the data I need (plus all the noise data)

Comment: hmm, I'll have to try and replicate what you need on my end and see if I can figure it out. Also, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by modifying your code somewhat. I'll edit the question to include the working code, but I'm marking this as the answer since your code is what I worked off of for it

Answer (score 1):

The hashtable key should be the common field, its value should be the entire row which you can simply access later as `$hashtable[$key]`:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv 'r:\1.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv 'r:\2.csv'

# build the index    
$indexKey = 'employee ID'
$index1 = @{}; foreach ($row in $csv1) { $index1[$row.$indexKey] = $row }

# use the index
$copyField = 'department number'
foreach ($row in $csv2) {
    if ($matched = $index1[$row.$indexKey]) {
        Add-Member @{$copyField = $matched.$copyField} -InputObject $row
    }
}

Export-Csv 'r:\merged.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -InputObject $csv2
```

The code doesn't use pipelines for overall speedup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I notice that you use the variable $matched in your if statement without declaring it elsewhere. When I run this code (after editing to fit my data) I get errors when it hits that line (specifically, 'Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.')

Comment: In PowerShell there's no need to declare variables. The problem is caused by something else and I can't really help without seeing the code. This is why it's so important to provide a sample of data in the question so that we don't have to guess blindly.

Comment: I realize you do not need to declare variables in the traditional sense, but when using them in an if statement, do you not have to at least set them equal to something for the loop to be able to check if the condition is true or not?

Comment: `=` in PowerShell is an assignment so my code simultaneously assigns and then checks if the result is not null.

Comment: I have added a data sample, although it is just a generic visualization of what I wrote in the question as I cannot actually release any of the data I am working on

Comment: I see it's `UserID` in the first one, but `User ID` in the second one. It means you can't use the same `$indexKey` variable. Instead use a literal string: `$row.UserID` for index-building of $csv1 and `$row.'User ID'` for $csv2 loop.

Comment: I tried editing the code in the way you suggest and am getting a .csv with the length and count of system strings instead of the data I want.

Comment: Well, I can't help without seeing the code/data, obviously.